# Azure data factory - Connect to local Mysql, a protected service on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a on-premises Mysql database on a linux server which is trusted; means that just certain IPs can connect to the database.

Is there a way to set a static IP for my data factory and trust it to my database.

Note: Beacause of security concerns, it's not a good idea to use IP range introduced in this linke https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your scenario by installing the [self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) software on a new or existing on-premises Windows server and follow those instructions for registering it in ADF.

Then you should edit your MySQL linked service in ADF and set it to use the self-hosted integration runtime.

Comment: So I can simply access the on-prem linux MySQL-server by connecting to it using an on-prem windows server where the SHIR is installed?

Comment: Correct @ThomasL.